# Building sparse array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a big array (say 500 entries) but most of the values are Null. How can i represent the array instead of having `[null, null ... 3, null, null, ...]`?

the array is passed to highcharts for plotting. Highcharts plots a point for every element in the array so I really don't need those `null`s.

Comment: How do you want it to be represented?

Comment: You got `null`s and you want the array not to have them, but you got to have them.I'm confused! What is it exactly that you want then?!

Comment: i want javascript to understand that I have a 500 entries array with lots of null but I do not want the code to show a giant block of null's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `array[200]` to something, it's not like JavaScript comes along behind you and sets `array[0]` through `array[199]`.  Arrays are automatically sparse.

So is the problem that if you ask for an uninitialized element, you get `undefined` back instead of `null`?   Or is there some other issue?

If it's the `undefined` vs `null` thing, then just add the `null`s after you initialize it, with a loop, instead of having to put them in the big literal blob:

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; ++i) { 
    if (typeof(array[i]) === 'undefined') { 
        array[i] = null; 
    } 
}
```

If you want `null`s out past what you initialized, replace `array.length` with whatever your maximum index needs to be (+1, or else change the `<` to `<=`).

Comment: a potential problem with this is Highcharts understands null but (probably) not undefined. eg: data=[null, 2, null ,4, null] will give a plot of with only 2 points with a gap in the middle

Comment: sadly, highcharts seems to not work with undefineds :(. Oh well, your answer would still make lots of sense tho :)